# How to enter the scores via the keyboard or from a scores file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, if-statement, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getInformationKeyBoard(int size, string Names[], int socres[]);
void getInformationFile(fstream& FileName, int size, string Names[], int scores[]);
void OpenTheFile(ifstream& FileName);
int main()
{
    const int size = 1024;
    string Name[size];
    int score[size];
    int NumberOfStudent;

    char choice;
    cout << "You want to enter your scores by your keyboard (A) or from your input (B): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A') // It will take information from keyboard
    {
        cout << "How many students do you want to enter: ";
        cin >> NumberOfStudent;
        getInformationKeyBoard(NumberOfStudent, Name, score);
    }

    else if (choice == 'b' || choice == 'B') // It will take information from file
    {
        ifstream FileName;
        OpenTheFile(FileName);
        FileName >> NumberOfStudent;
        getInformationFile(FileName, NumberOfStudent, Name, score);
        FileName.close;
    }
    else // If you choice is not A,a or B,b
        cout << "Your did not follow the right instruction.";
}

void getInformationKeyBoard(int size, string Names[], int scores[]) // Information from keyboard
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Student First Name and Last Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, Names[1]);
        do
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". Enter the score between 1 and 100: ";
            cin >> scores[i];
        } while (scores[i] > 100 || scores[i] < 0 );

    }
}

void OpenTheFile(ifstream& FileName) // Open the File
{
    char again;
    string InputFile;
    bool close = false;
    while (close == false)
    {
        cout << "Open the file: ";
        cin >> InputFile;
        ifstream ReadFromFile(InputFile);
        if (ReadFromFile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Succeed to open the file!\n";
            close = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Failed to open the file!\n";
            do {

                cout << "Do you want to do it again(Y) or Close (N)? ";
                cin >> again;
            } while (again != 'y' && again != 'Y' && again != 'n' && again != 'N');

            if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
                close = false;
            else
                close = true;
        }

    }

}

void getInformationFile(ifstream& FileName, int size, string Names[], int scores[]) // Get information from the File
{
    string FName, LName;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            FileName >> FName >> LName;
            Names[i] = FName + " " + LName;
            FileName >> scores[i];
        }


}
```

My program didn't continue when the user enter B to open the scores file. Can someone help me with this problem.

1. If the user chooses keyboard, then the user should be first asked the total number of scores they want to enter and then ask the user for each student name and test score.
2. If the user chooses file, then ask the user for the file name and location.  The first line in the file should be the total number of scores followed by one student name and their test score per line.
   for example:

   > ```
   > 3
   > F1 L1
   > 82
   > F2 L2
   > 87
   > F3 L3
   > 92
   > ```

And I wonder how to make more functions to

1. Determine lowest score
2. Determine highest score
3. Calculate mean/average score

I just a beginner of C++, please make it easy so I can understand the program well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please paste the errors you are seeing on the console, to help find the issue in program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better method for these assignments is to use one container of records, instead of several containers of one element each.

Let us define a record as:

```
struct Score_Record
{
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
  int score;
};
```

For simplicity, let us choose a vector as our container.  To save keystrokes, we'll use a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<Score_Record> Container_Type;
```

If we want to be able to load a record from either file or keyboard, we'll use the concept of a generic stream:

```
void Input_Score(std::istream& input, Score_Record& sr)
{
  input >> sr.first_name;
  input >> sr.last_name;
  input >> sr.score;
  input.ignore(100000, '\n'); // Synchronize to next input line.
}
```

So, to input from the keyboard:

```
Score_Record sr;
Input_Record(cin, sr);
```

To input from a file:

```
ifstream data_file("my_data.txt");
Input_Record(data_file);
```

Here's some code to find the maximum score:

```
Container_Type  database;
// read into database
const size_t quantity = database.size();
int maximum_score = -1;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  if (database[i].score > maximum_score)
  {
    maximum_score = database[i].score;
  }
}
```

The lowest, average and mean can be calculated similar to the above loop.

**Edit 1: A simpler solution**
If we keep the responsibility of all things score related to the class, we can let the class read its values from the input stream:

```
class Score_Record
{
  public:
    Score_Record()
    { ; }
    virtual ~Score_Record();
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Score_Record& sr);
  private:
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    int         score;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Score_Record& sr)
{
  input >> sr.first_name;
  input >> sr.last_name;
  input >> sr.score;
  input.ignore(100000, '\n'); // synchronize to next text line.
  return input;
}
```

To read a single `Score_Record` from a file:

```
Score_Record sr;
data_file >> sr;
```

To read an entire file into a database:

```
Container_Type database;
while (database >> sr)
{
  database.push_back(sr);
}
```

Comment: I quite not understand, can you make it more simple.

Comment: What parts do you not understand?

Comment: The input file and read the first name, last name, and scores

Comment: Reading from an input file should be discussed in a quality C++ book.  The `operator >>`, known as the extraction operator, reads characters into a string until a space is encountered; regardless of whether the stream is the keyboard or file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getInformationKeyBoard(int size, string Names[], int socres[]);
void getName(string & name);
int main()
{
    const int size = 1024;
    string Name[size];
    int score[size];
    int NumberOfStudent;

    char choice;
    cout << "You want to enter your scores by your keyboard (A) or from your input (B): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A') // It will take information from keyboard
    {
        cout << "How many students do you want to enter: ";
        cin >> NumberOfStudent;
        getInformationKeyBoard(NumberOfStudent, Name, score);
    }

    else if (choice == 'b' || choice == 'B') // It will take information from file
    {
        string NameA;
        getName(NameA);
        GetInformationFile(nameA, NumberOfStudent, Name, score); // This is where my program get an error





    }
    else // If you choice is not A,a or B,b
        cout << "Your did not follow the right instruction.";


    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void getInformationKeyBoard(int size, string Names[], int scores[]) // Information from keyboard
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Student First Name and Last Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, Names[1]);
        do
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". Enter the score between 1 and 100: ";
            cin >> scores[i];
        } while (scores[i] > 100 || scores[i] < 0 );

    }
}

void GetInformationFile(fstream name, int size, string Names[], int scores[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        string line;
        getline(name, line);
            Names[i];
            scores[i];
    }

}




void getName(string & name)
{
    char again = 'Y';
    bool close = false;

    while (close == false)
    {
    cout << "Enter name of file: ";
    cin >> name;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(name.c_str());
    close = true;
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File did not open correctly" << endl;
        do 
        {
            cout << "Do you want to do it again(Y) or Close (N):  ";
            cin >> again;
        } 
        while (again != 'y' && again != 'Y' && again != 'n' && again != 'N');
        if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
            close = false;
        else
            close = true;
    }
    }

}
```